# Java Script object fields access

Tags: javascript

```
var friends = new Object ();
friends.bill = new Object ();
    friends.bill.firstName = 'Bill';
    friends.bill.lastName = 'Gates';

friends.steve = new Object ();
    friends.steve.firstName = 'Steve';
    friends.steve.lastName = 'Jobs';



    var search1 = function (name) {
        for (var x in friends){
            if (name == friends.x.firstName) {

                console.log(friends.x.firstName, friends.x.lastName);

            }
        }
    }

var search2 = function (name) {
        for (var x in friends){
            if (name == friends[x].firstName) {

                console.log(friends[x].firstName, friends[x].lastName);

            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone explain why search2 works just fine(printing details of object in friends with same name), but search1 isnt working.

I was sure object.x is same as object[x]...
If it not, what is the difference ?
Many thanks!

Comment: object.x == object['x']

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Comment: object.x != object[x]

Comment: Imagine that statement with a value for `x`. For example: if `x = "bill"` - `object."bill"` doesn't look right, does it? Whereas `object["bill"]` looks perfectly alright.

Comment: x is used as a index, and a index can't be referenced as a property